# CRM 2011 - Weird behavior form when clicking on own record link in an associated view or subgrid

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, outlook-2010

Before I start asking my question, I can say that the system where I tried it out has Office 2010 with the "CRM 2011 Outlook Client" installed.  I just installed the Rollup 12 and the Error still occures (on all other systems too).  The error only occurs in “Outlook” and not on the “Web”-version.

To explain our problem it's better to work with an Example:
We have a "Project A" and under the "Project A" we have two opportunities ("Opportunity A" and "Opportunity B").  We've adapted the views on opportunity so that they have several columns: "Project", "Opportunity Name", "Createdon".

When we open "Project A" and we go to the associated view (or subgrid) we see our defined views.  When we click on the "Project A"-link (referring to the same record), the form blocks and there is nothing we can do.  We can click on "Save" or "Save and close" or "Lookups", but nothing happens.  It’s just like the “Form” JavaScript stopped working.

On "Internet Explorer 8" we had a "Stack overflow at line: 0"-error, but with the IE9 we don't have the message anymore.

Does anyone has the same problem as mentioned above?  Is there a way to solve this or do we have to ask a fix at microsoft.  We can't delete the column for the view, because it's used on several other entities too.

Comment: Did my reply help? If so, check it as answer. If not, please explain what more is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I recognized a few weeks ago that a solution I had working in on-line and on-premise, just didn't fly in the Outlook client. Totally different issue **but** I believe both have the same origin.

The problem, as far I've seen, occurs because the client for Outlook doesn't use the IE rendering engine. Instead, it relies on the legacy Trident version, which is some kind of IE8-ish thingy included for backward compatibility reason (or not, depending on whom you ask).

So, in our case, we had to adapt the solution to work with IE8 (although the clients run it under IE9 and IE10). Then, it started working properly in all versions. Weird in my view.

Comment: Thx for the answer.  What do you mean bij adapting the solution?  It didn't work in IE8 either though.  It has nothing to do with own customizations,  because the error even happens on normal entities. I know it has to do with the "IE"-rendering stuff from outlook, but I didn't find a good work-around.

Comment: It might be the case that my issue was a bit different from yours but as a general first-shot trouble-shooting I'd suggest that you check if CRM and the client for Outlook are running the same version of roll-up. My issue only happened to customized entities. Are you sure you get the problematic behavior on the default, uncustomized entities as well?